# Typescript generic parameter typing for curried function

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, functor, currying, generic-type-argument

Trying to type a curried function which takes a functor first and then an object

```
type TestType = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  hello: string;
};

type CordinateType = {
  data: TestType;
  id: string;
};

const transform = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  fntor: (val: T[K]) => any
) => (obj: T) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: fntor(v) }), {});

const testData: CordinateType = {
  id: "uuid-222-uuid",
  data: {
    x: -3,
    y: 2,
    hello: "test"
  }
};

const positive = (x) => (Number.isInteger(x) ? Math.abs(x) : x);

const result = { ...testData, data: transform(positive)(testData) };
console.log("result", result);
```

Transform is simple function that takes functor and maps over an object.

The main issue is that type of result.data is `{}`, instead it should be `TestType`

[image: Edit lucid-mopsa-pqudl]

This is sample react app, the setState hook function is not able to deduce proper type

[image: Edit lucid-mopsa-pqudl]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You can pass one of the generic parameters (`T`). Note that a default value needs to be used for the second parameter because we either let typescript figure out the parameters or pass them explicitly.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

type PointType = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  comment: string;
};

type CordinateType = {
  data: PointType;
  id: string;
};

const transform = <T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
  fntor: (val: T[K]) => any
) => (obj: T) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: fntor(v) }),
    {}
  ) as T;
const positive = (x: any) => (Number.isInteger(x) ? Math.abs(x) : x);

export default function App() {
  const [cordinate, setCordinate] = useState<CordinateType>({
    id: "uuid-xxx-uuid",
    data: {
      x: 1,
      y: -2,
      comment: "initial-point"
    }
  });

  const updateCoord = useCallback(() => {
    // setCordinate((old) => ({ ...old, data: old.data })); // this works type
    setCordinate((old) => ({
      ...old,
      data: transform<PointType>(positive)(old.data)
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Cordinate</h1>

      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(cordinate.data)}</pre>
      </div>

      <button onClick={updateCoord}>Update</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit elastic-bash-s6m6h]

---

```
fntor: (val: K) => K
```

The type of `fntor` is incorrect because `val` isn't a key of the object, it's one of the values.

Here's the fixed code:

[image: Edit lucid-mopsa-pqudl]

```
const transform = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  fntor: (val: T[K]) => any
) => (obj: T) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: fntor(v) }), {});

const testData: Record<string, any> = {
  x: -3,
  y: 2,
  hello: "test"
};

const positive = (x: any) => (Number.isInteger(x) ? Math.abs(x) : x);

const result = transform(positive)(testData);
console.log("result", result);
```

Comment: thanks for fntor update, i have edited the question further, please check

Comment: @vito check the updated answer

Comment: its still not able to take the type, please see second codepen link

Comment: @vito updated your react code and added it

Comment: thanks you very much, didn't understood the ```= keyof T``` part, please add some explaination to that which might be helpful to others.
Can typecasting ```transform<PointType>``` be avoided, can it auto deduce